# jQuery - Smooth scroll only working to top - need it to work to bottom aswell

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to use a smooth scroll for my href elements.
The only problem is that i can only get it to do it upwards.

The live site is [here](http://mediemaskinen.dk/)

If you click on the box "Webdesign" it should do a smooth scrool down to the .content.
The same thing if you hit the button of the bottom of that content it should scroll up to the top again smoooth(That works fine) - Its downwards to the start of the "webdesign" content it doesnt work.

script used in the bottom of the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(){ 
var contentPosTop = $('.content').position().top;

$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: contentPosTop
}, 1500);
});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebug it says that contentPosTop is 0. I don't know why, but I didn't look into it because I don't think you need to calculate that value. You will scroll down the same distance in any option (the logo + the menu height ). Try  something like 660 and see if it works. At least in my test it did.

```
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(){ 
$('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: 660 }, 1500);
});
```

EDIT: To go back to the top

```
   $('#starter-template').click(function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 1500);
    });
```

Comment: Okay, now its scrolling down, i testet locally - Tho it now doesn't take me back to the top hitting the to top button.

Comment: That is fairly easy, use the same thing but with scrollTop:0 check my edit.

Comment: That doesn't take me back to the top.

<script type="text/javascript">
$("a[href^='#']").click(function(){ 
$('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: 660}, 1500);
});

   $('#starter-template').click(function(event) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 1500);
    });
</script>

Comment: let me try it. I may have a typo

Comment: i changed #starter-template to #webend, which is the button to take me to top - But it takes like 3 seconds before it starts taking me to the top.

Comment: yes, I was trying something like that too. Change the speed from 1500 to 100 or to fast, that shouldn't be it. It shouldn't instant movement, but slow.

Comment: I thinks it is because the site needs to load that the content collapses before it can go back to top - The speed just makes the scrolling faster - But it still takes 2-3 seconds before it starts to scroll.

Comment: figured it out - the $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100); should be $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100);

Thank you very much Ricardo - you saved my day by guiding me in the right direction :)